# Wifi Problem on lumia 720

Tags: wifi

I have a Lumia 720 and from time to time it simply won't connect to my work wifi.

At home, university and some other places it works fine. But some times it won't work at my company. For other people it is working.

Somebody has any clue? I have restarted it and it won't work.

I use Denim (ver. 8.10.14219.341).

Comment: When you say "won't connect" do you mean it "won't connect automatically", or it "won't connect, even when manually forcing a connection"? Have you spoken to your workplace's local, friendly IT staff to find out if their network requires something special like a certificate to connect?

Comment: it won't connect, even when manually forcing a connection. I have already talked to the IT guy and there is nothing like that. Yesterday it was working fine but today it won't connect. It says that the wifi is not responding and to try again later.

Comment: Are close enough to the hot spot?

Comment: Yes. I'm the only having this problem at work, and i'm the only one with a windows phone.

Comment: Even when I am in my house, the Wi-Fi won't connect in my Lumia 720. This is because the router denies access because of a misbehave rule about the maximum number of connected devices. To solve this issue I just restart the router.

Comment: I talked with the IT staff and there is no connection limit. And there are 30 people using this wi-fi.

Comment: That just means that your coworkers' phones and the router all have the same error ;) Usually turning my WiFi off and back on or restarting my phone fixes this problem for me.

Comment: But the IT staff have already looked into the router and there is no error. I have already restarted my phone, i even restored to factory settings. When i restored (about 2 weeks ago) it worked fine until yesterday.

Comment: Do you have Bluetooth turned on/connected? I have an issue that when I connect my Bluetooth, it will break my phone's wifi connection.

Answer (score 1):

hey most probably It it might be an issue of static IP:
find the detailed solution here: [reference link](http://youthhworld.blogspot.com/2015/08/windows-phone-wifi-connectivity-problem.html)
Or you may find this video helpful : [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRUMQiVSr6k)

As I stated The reason might be Static IP, which is a new feature introduced in the LUMIA CYAN update with windows phone 8.1.

So you will have to turn off static IP, possibly if the settings does not match the particular default gateway your are trying to connect.

You can find the detailed description in the links given.
The blog has some more reasons mentioned in the article, but mainly this is the major issues concerned with the phone, other reasons are related to router and internet.

Comment: You should summarize the content of the sites, not just link to them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to settings -> Wi-Fi -> Wi-Fi sense. Turn off "automatically connect to Wi-Fi hotspot".

Then go back to Wi-Fi -> manage -> under known devices delete the name of the router/access point.

If you can see it there if not then go back to Wi-Fi and connect to it